# How Can One change the MS-DOS prompt font color?

Tags: command-line, fonts, colors, windows-98

## How Can One change the MS-DOS prompt font color?

MS-DOS is really old, and being the grandpappy of the computers it is really hard to find support for it.

I have these tried suggestions from websites:
http://www.easydos.com/menucolor.html
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/95099
http://www.computerhope.com/color.htm

I have edited:
Config.sys (It now says 'Menucolor= 2,0' )
C:\Windows\color.txt (It now says 'green')

Still not working.
Anyone have any idead on how to do this?

**Notes**

Before you suggest 'color a', Ms-Dos is not the cmd. I already tried that.
It is possible! There are multiple ms-dos viruses that have done this effectively.
I am running MS-DOS from Windows 98 on a virtual machine.

Comment: "I am running MS-DOS 6.22 on a virtual machine." ... I know this won't answer your question but... why?

Comment: Whoops... I meant I am running MS-DOS from Windows 98 on a virtual machine!

Comment: I just like looking at and playing with  MS-DOS. It is old and pretty cool.                                              I'm sorry I can't fully explain. :P

Comment: If my memory serves me right one way to do this was via a crazy little assembler included in DOS, I cannot remember it’s name. The assembler was accessing the BIOS routines included in the ROM - which is not part of any virtualization I know of today. Dr. Dobb’s had these few lines of tricks in hordes, but again - you most likely need real hardware with the BIOS routines on the ROM IC to make it work. You could search the archives of Dr. Dobb’s for them.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 : you must be a vintage/nostalgia lover... ;-)

Comment: @RookieTEC9 That assembler was called 'debug', a standalone program not part of msdos.sys, and it is still pretty well documented on the web. Good luck!

Comment: @arch-abit Virtualization software needs to provide the BIOS routines and compatible in-VM memory mappings for things to work at all. If they didn't, it is highly unlikely that Windows 98 would start at all.

Comment: Michael - debug.com is an assembler for MS-DOS. It was probably created to try and BYPASS the ever-evil BIOS.
Back in those days...  Virtualization is NOT to reproduce things far passed, but to show us things yet to come!

Comment: I'm on it, should have an answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `debug` to write a short COM file. When you run `debug` you'll get a single dash prompt, enter the following (including blank lines) and you'll get a file `color.com` in your current working directory:

```
a 100
mov ah, 06
xor al, al
xor cx, cx
mov dx, 184f
mov bh, 07
int 10
mov ah, 4c
xor al, al
int 21

rcx
e
ncolor.com
w
q
```

It calls `int 10 ah=06` to clear the screen, setting the cursor at the bottom and filling with attributes in `bh`. High nibble is background, low is foreground, colors are:

- 0 = black
- 1 = blue
- 2 = green
- 3 = cyan
- 4 = red
- 5 = purple
- 6 = yellow
- 7 = white
- 8 = light black
- 9 = light blue
- A = light green
- B = light cyan
- C = light red
- D = light purple
- E = light yellow
- F = light white

(Thus bit 4 is high intensity.) To get red background with black foreground change 07 to 40.

Parsing the command line args to set colors is non-trivial, so just hard code your favorite one. Or do this in debug to update it:

```
debug color.com
e 10a
40
w
q
```

Attribute is stored in location 010A, updating it directly is easier than typing it all again.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done without Qbasic. We will run a small program that will modify the screen colors for the command prompt.

The `screen` qbasic command will be of much use.

Run this QBASIc program:

```
 SCREEN 0
 COLOR 26
```

Note: you can only have digits from 0-7

Comment: If you do cls, the screen will revert back to the original color.

Answer (score 2):

If you load ANSI.SYS then define the DOS prompt (for example):

c:>prompt $e[1;33m$p$g

you can change the prompt color and the prompt itself.

Changes the cmd.exe command prompt.

```
PROMPT [text]

  text    Specifies a new command prompt.

Prompt can be made up of normal characters and the following special codes:

  $A   & (Ampersand)
  $B   | (pipe)
  $C   ( (Left parenthesis)
  $D   Current date
  $E   Escape code (ASCII code 27)
  $F   ) (Right parenthesis)
  $G   > (greater-than sign)
  $H   Backspace (erases previous character)
  $L   < (less-than sign)
  $N   Current drive
  $P   Current drive and path
  $Q   = (equal sign)
  $S     (space)
  $T   Current time
  $V   Windows version number
  $_   Carriage return and linefeed
  $$   $ (dollar sign)
```

Comment: This link describes changing the prompt in DOS: http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/z-prompt.html

Comment: This link describes ansi.sys commands: http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/v-ansi-commands.html

Comment: Note: In prompt the $e[ prefix sets prompt color.